# Textarea not aligned because md-maxlength

Tags: html, css, angularjs

The options of my form are not aligned because the md-maxlength attribute makes that line to be higher than the rest, as shown in the picture below.

[image: Textarea higher than the rest]

I want to put that textarea one line down and keep the others as they are.
Here is the code which generate all the textareas.

```
<textarea ng-switch-when="text"
    ng-model="$ctrl.assetData[rowNumber][column.modelPropertyText]"
    ng-required="::column.required"
    ng-disabled="column.disabled"
    rows="1"
    maxlength="{{column.maxlength}}"
    md-maxlength="column.maxlength"
    >
</textarea>
```

How can I move a line down the cases where md-maxlenght is not null?

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 0; /* or px margin to bottom */
}
```

Note that you have to set display to block for "margin:auto" takes effect